# Rest service messing up strings with double quotes

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

Note that my question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602472/encoding-issue-service-stack-quotes-and-angle-bracket-being-stripped/14219903#14219903) but since I can't figure out how to add a comment to the accepted answer asking for clarification, I have to create a new question.

I have a rest service, similar to this:

```
namespace My.API
{
    [Route("/event/{Id}", Verbs = "POST")]
    public class EventRequest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }

    public class EventService : Service
    {
        public object Post(EventRequest request)
        {
            // Do something with request.Content
        }
    }
}
```

When I make a post request with the following form data:

```
Content=%22this+is+a+%22+test
```

request.Content contains

```
this is a " tes
```

Note that the first doublequote is missing, and the t at the end of test is missing.

Now, the accepted answer in the other question linked above says that we need to encode the string, but I am wondering if there is anyway that I can change the behaviour of this. I am trying to create a public api, and if the clients of the api have to encode the string in a certain way then I think that will cause errors. They should just be able to provide a normal string.

Basically, the following jQuery ajax call should work:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "api/event/" + id,
  type: "POST",
  data: {Content : content}
});
```

Where content is the raw/unencoded string, which jQuery will perform form url encoding on before passing to the service. The service should just return the original raw string.

Comment: I have also posted this issue on [github](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/703)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default ServiceStack decodes QueryString/FormData params using the built-in [JSV Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/wiki/JSV-Format), which is what allows ServiceStack to deserialize nested complex types on the QueryString.

The issue is that `"this is a " test` is not a valid JSV string since it contains reserved chars that's not escaped.

To resolve this issue we're now skipping deserializing JSV values for string properties as [seen in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/4495578abdf24532f129280cc394b681d9d87573) which will be available on the next release of ServiceStack v3.9.48+.

Comment: Excellent. When will this be released?

Comment: We announce new releases on the [ServiceStack Google+ Group](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/112445368900682590445).

Answer (score 0):

The rules of the web say that you must encode strings to ensure they pass safely.  If you don't encode, then all parties cannot guarantee how to read/write the data.

I think it's perfectly reasonable to expect users to need to encode strings if they need to be encoded.

Comment: Why is it that when when the form content is `Content=this+%22is+a+%22+test` it works fine. My service is expecting a string, the form data contains a string. In both cases the the value of content is properly form url encoded, but on the service side service stack is messing up the parsing/decoding. It seems like service stack is looking for a " at the begining and doing something special in that case, which I don't want.

Comment: It's probably seeing the double quote at the start and assuming your string is quoted at both ends.  When the first character is not a double quote, then it does not do that processing.

Comment: To me this seems like a bug in ServiceStack. The content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, not `application/json` or `text/javascript` or some other type, so ServiceStack shouldn't be doing any weird parsing/deserializing. It should just stick the values of the form data into the request dto as given.